# Botbuilder Update Image Flask

Tags: python, flask, botframework

I am using Flask to build an Azure bot with botbuilder library, and I use a local image in a herocard. However, when I go to my source code and change the content of this local image or even delete this local image, the bot still sends a herocard with the old image. Why it happen and how to fix it because I need to change the content of the png file for a user input?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Perhaps the image is getting cached somewhere, or maybe you have multiple copies at different paths, and the one you're changing is not the one shown?

Either way, more info is needed before someone can give you an answer.